# Where can I find onSubmit form field check using Firefox DevTools?

Tags: javascript, forms, silverstripe, devtools, onsubmit

I integrated the Google reCaptcha into a website form. Before, on form submit the webapp checked if all form filed were filled in. After I integrated the reCaptcha, this form check does not run anymore and the form ist send even when the fields are empty.

I tried to find the javascript that does the checks but could not find it. I ran the Firefox DevTools Runtime Analysis and checked the Flame Chart to see the javascript call stack. There I found some jquery functions but afaik that can not be the whole story, as form field checks are not done by jQuery.

By what menas can I find out, what javascript function is called to do the check? Or could the checks be done elsewhere, e.g. in CSS.

Strange too: The posted error message "Please fill in this field" can not be found anywhere in the entire project code. I checked in my IDE.

The Webpage uses twitter Bootstrap, jQuery 1.12.4 and runs on Silverstripe CMS 3.6 with userforms module (although this particular form appears in the correseponding page template).

I appreciate any hint. I allready spent hours with this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - Please add a [mcve] to your queston

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 problems there:
- first: I had a submit button with id="submit" as in Google reCaptcha documentation example (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible). However, this can cause "confusing failures" if used with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/submit/). So I renamed the button id="submit_button" and the form was submitted.
- second: Form validation was done by HTML5 which I did not know exists.This was activated with the "required" attributes is the input form fields. Shame on me!

My form now works and looks like this:

```
<h2>Anfrage</h2>
<form action="formaction.php" method="post" id="form-offer"  class="form-std form-offer" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset>
        <label>Firma * <input name="firma" required="" type="text"></label>
        <select name="anrede" required="">
            <option value="">Anrede *</option>
            <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
            <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
        </select>
        <label>Name und Vorname Kontaktperson *<input name="vorname" required="" type="text"></label>
        <label>PLZ &amp; Ort *<input name="ort" required="" type="text"></label>
        <label>Adresse *<input name="adresse" required="" type="text"></label>
        <select name="land" required="">
            <option value="">Land *</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Ägypten">Ägypten</option>
            <option value="Aland">Aland</option>
            <option value="Albanien">Albanien</option>
        </select>
        <label>E-Mail *<input name="email" required="" type="email"></label>
        <label>Telefon *<input name="telephone" required="" type="text"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="g-recaptcha"
         data-sitekey="sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"
         data-size="invisible"
         data-callback="formSubmit">
    </div>

    <button id="submit_button">Send<i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i></button>

    <input name="block" value="167" type="hidden">
    <input name="locale" value="de_DE" type="hidden">
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="body.min.css">


<script src="jquery-12.js"></script>
<script defer="" src="main.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<script>
    (function($, document, undefined){

        $('#form-offer').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            grecaptcha.reset();
            grecaptcha.execute();
        });

    })(jQuery, document, undefined);

    function formSubmit(response) {
        // submit the form which now includes a g-recaptcha-response input
        var myForm = document.getElementById("form-offer");
        myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```